# Adding HTTP request header to WCF request

Tags: c#, ajax, http, http-headers, httprequest

I have a WCF service consume by both AJAX and C# application,
I need to send a parameter through the HTTP request header.

On my AJAX I have added the following and it works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this.tenantAdminService,
    beforeSend: function (req, methodName)
    {
        req.setRequestHeader("AdminGUID", adminGuid);
    }
```

and on the WCF server side I do the following to Get the header:

```
string adminGUID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["AdminGUID"];
```

What is the C# equivalent? 
How can I send the http request header that will also be consume by my WCF server?

I need to add the parameter to HTTP request header and not to the message header,

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simplest way to this is using [WebOperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.aspx) at the following way:

```
Service1Client serviceClient = new Service1Client();
using (new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope((System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel)serviceClient.InnerChannel))
{
    System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("AdminGUID", "someGUID");
    serviceClient.GetData();
}
```

Taken from this [post](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2011/06/04/wcf-how-to-append-header-to-http-request.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Make a new WebRequest object of type HttpWebRequest. Set the header and get the response.

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("myURL") as HttpWebRequest;
req.Headers.Add("AdminGUID", "value");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

for a more in depth example of webrequest, see this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

Comment: Can I do this in a neater way? so that I wont have to put URL? since I already have service reference that contains all methods

Comment: You add the web service directly to your project c#. VS will automatically generate classes for you to call your web service directly but it might not give the option to add a request header, when calling the web service.