# Customising HTTP header in calls to ASMX service

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2017, http-headers, asmx

I am trying to add an HTTP header in calls to an ASMX service.

[Some SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132887/adding-soap-headers-to-asmx-service-requests) talk about SOAP headers, which is not what I want, as that involves adding elements to the body of the POST message, namely this portion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope ...>
    <soap:Body ...>
        <q2:HeaderIn ...>
```

What I want is to add to this portion of the request - the HTTP headers:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://..."
Host: ...
Content-Length: 2018
```

To this end I found [a post from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532503/how-to-add-token-authentication-to-web-services-for-auth-token) which describes adding a Service Reference, choosing the older Web Reference, then selecting a proxy class and overriding `GetWebRequest`. Unfortunately, in `Visual Studio 2017`, choosing an alternative proxy class does not appear to be an option. Otherwise, this would have been a great option.

**Question:** Am I missing something (obvious) which leads to selecting the proxy class for a generated ASMX service client class?

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886660/how-to-add-http-header-to-soap-client/22998513#22998513) [(also this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856362/adding-http-request-header-to-wcf-request/13858335#13858335) talks about using `OperationContextScope` to add custom headers to a WCF request. I figured I could add the service as a WCF service and use this. Converting the solution code from using the generated ASMX client namespace to the generated WCF client was simply a matter of changing the namespaces in the `using` statements - everything else was the same.

Unfortunately, actually making calls using a WCF client to the ASMX service fails because the generated XML in the request body is completely different.

**Question:** Am I missing something about using ASMX over WCF which causes this problem or is it simply that it is not possible? ([This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/asmx) would appear to indicate that it is possible.)

Comment: How do you call the ASMX service(XML web service)? I think there is no difference between a WCF client and a client proxy object. It is the object that initated an Http request. As long as we add an Http header to the proxy object, it should work. On my side, I call the ASMX service by adding service reference(not web reference), subsequently use WebOperationContext which is a convenient wrapper around your above solution, finally get the right HTTP header.

Comment: Bizarrely, the generated Service Reference client does not produce the same request body that the Web Reference client does. However, I do have a solution, which does not involve replacing the client class - see my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309767/adding-custom-http-headers-to-web-service-proxy/1310055#1310055) which states that a partial class in a separate file should be used to override `GetWebRequest()` and insert the custom headers.